# How to replicate this 2-1 layout in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I've looked into all of the layout options in the docs, and I am not allowed to use FXML. I don't understand where to start with configuring the 3 containers in the scene. [image]

Comment: Anything you can do in FXML you can do with Java code. How about an `HBox`, with a `VBox` containing the two elements on the left, and then the element on the right.

Comment: Or you could use a `BorderPane` with the CCTV panel in the center, and a `VBox` containing the other two panes in the left.

Comment: For clarity, I want to understand just the basic layout of the 3 containers, as in their positioning, padding,  and etc. I don't need to know the details inside each container, e.g. buttons, sliders, imageview, and etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: Or you could use a `GridPane`, and set the `rowSpan` of the CCTV pane to 2...

Comment: What they're trying to say is that there are many ways of doing this in JavaFX. I tend to abuse BorderLayout, myself. I'd put the left column in a VBox in the left of a BorderLayout. The CCTV I'd put in the center (which probably has a BorderLayout of it's own with the four images in the center and the title in the top and the buttons in the bottom (in their own grid layout)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this; probably the most immediate is to put the two panes on the left in a `VBox`, and then use a `BorderPane`, with the `VBox` on the left and the "CCTV" pane in the center. This looks like:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LayoutExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane lighting = new Pane(); 
        lighting.getChildren().add(new Label("Lighting"));
        Pane heating = new Pane();
        heating.getChildren().add(new Label("Heating"));
        Pane cctv = new Pane();
        cctv.getChildren().add(new Label("CCTV"));

        lighting.getStyleClass().add("control-pane");
        heating.getStyleClass().add("control-pane");
        cctv.getStyleClass().add("control-pane");

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane() ;
        VBox left = new VBox();
        left.getChildren().add(lighting);
        left.getChildren().add(heating);

        // expand both panes in left to full width of vbox:
        left.setFillWidth(true);
        // add vertical space between panes:
        left.setSpacing(5);
        // allocate extra vertical space equally to both panes in left:
        VBox.setVgrow(lighting, Priority.ALWAYS);
        VBox.setVgrow(heating, Priority.ALWAYS);

        root.setLeft(left);
        root.setCenter(cctv);

        // Add a left margin to the center pane to give it some space:
        BorderPane.setMargin(cctv, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("layout-style.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.setWidth(800);
        primaryStage.setHeight(640);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

This CSS isn't quite right, but gives you an idea how to add the borders:

```css
.control-pane {
  -fx-background-color: -fx-body-color, -fx-outer-border, -fx-body-color ;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2 ;
  -fx-background-radius: 0, 1, 0 ;
  -fx-padding: 3 ;

  /** Just to demo empty boxes: **/
  -fx-min-width: 300px ;
  -fx-min-height: 300px ;
 }
```

This looks like:

[image]

You could also use a `HBox` as the root, and set the `hgrow` on each to prioritize extra horizontal space on the CCTV pane. Or use a `GridPane`, and set the row span of the CCTV pane to 2. There are probably many other ways to do this.